# LiDAR Lines Having Erratic Patterns

Tags: remote-sensing, lidar, las, point-cloud, lidar-analyst

I have processed a LiDAR data and produced LAS files for an area that was flown by my team. We have processed some areas and the outputs were pretty good. I observed that we are now getting erratic and wavy pattern when the LAS is produced.

There was no error observed while processing the SBET used to create the LAS files or flight operator issues.

[image]

Comment: How were you processing data before, and after this problem occurred? Can you describe the software, and the steps used in the workflow?Maybe sharing sample files which were ok, and sample files you could not process correctly? What do colors represent in the picture? Are they flight swaths/lines? You need to provide much more details than you did, so people may have a chance to help you.